# Piping the output of a Python process A ( generating documents) to other Python process B ( inserting documents into DataBase like Mongo )

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, pipe

It might be a silly question. But, I am looking for an efficient Pythonic way of following problem.

I am having a `process A` which keeps on producing some documents ( a compute heavy process ) .

I have to run `process B` consume the output from A ( either as a single doc or a batch of docs ) and insert it into MongoDB. ( `batch is preferable` ) .

What is the most efficient way of piping A to B. Is piping the best approach here?

I can wait for A to complete and then B to start. But I feel its not efficient.

Comment: Did you try setting the standard output of A to be the stdin of B?

Comment: It depends what your motivation is. If your aim is to produce all the documents as soon as possible and then put them in a DB, you should use multiprocessing on the document production till they are all done, then put them in the DB. If your aim is to keep constant good throughput, maybe run 2-4 document production processes in multiprocessing and one DB writer process that all the producers send document names to via a multiprocessing queue. Or just run 4 processes that each repeatedly generate a document and immediately put it in the DB themselves before generating the next - uses less disk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - The main problem here is the delay. As mentioned  down A is 10x times slower than B. I mean  A will take approximately 1 minute to produce 10 documents, but B need only few milliseconds to upload it into DB.

Comment: So if A produces 1 doc every 6 seconds, let A also write the doc to DB and it will take 6.004 seconds per doc. If that's not good enough, multiprocess A with 4 processes and it will take 1.501 seconds per doc. What are you hoping to gain by leaving processed documents around waiting to be sent to DB?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Yes thats what we are doing now. I am checking for the best approach. Both from technical as well as standard way of dealing these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

It sounds like A may take > 10x the time that B takes.
If so, then just use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).
Have B wait patiently while the A child sends document to stdout,
then insert document into DB.

Alternatively, perhaps A & B take comparable amounts of time,
and batching is desirable.
Have a bunch of A jobs write to `/tmp/temp.${PID}`,
then `mv` (`os.rename()`) the completed file
into a `/tmp/out/` directory.
Have B periodically shovel such files into the DB,
unlinking each one as it goes.

Either way, you will be chewing on lots of CPU cycles
as your `for` loop visits many inputs,
and you'd like to keep more than one core busy.
Enter multiprocessing.

Convert your `for` loop into a `map` call,
for example: `list(map(str, range(3)))`
will turn `[0, 1, 2]` into `['0', '1', '2']`.
Of course, *your* function will be far more
compute intensive than `str`.

With that in hand, you're in a good position
to fork off a bunch of children that will all
run the same function:

```
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        p.map(my_func, bunch_of_inputs)
```